# Change text on each click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm not much of coder but this should be pretty straight forward:
The user is clicking on a div which plays a random audio file out of an array.
That works. Now I do need to display the number of the audio track (like "1 out of 5"),
and I can't seem to make that work for some reason.
I don't care if it's a button or a paragraph, i'm styling it in webflow anyway, I just need the text to be updated with each click.

What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```js
var audio = new Audio();
var audiolist = new Array('https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504645/BatShevaAudio/chiaki_tpast4.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504643/BatShevaAudio/sean_mzegyf.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504636/BatShevaAudio/yoni_z4suqd.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504636/BatShevaAudio/Billy_x8srx0.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504627/BatShevaAudio/Matan_sj77wi.mp3');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

function play() {
  if (audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
  }
  let rndnumber = getRandomInt(0, 4);

  audio.src = audiolist[rndnumber];
  audio.play();
  document.getElementById("audioNumber").innnerHTML = rndnumber;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play()" id="rndnumber"></button>
```

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML` use `textContent`.

Comment: Typo in  `innerHTML`

Comment: @User863 Thanks! I fixed it but still no luck.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SKJoy2001/0j4wyhLs/3/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no HTML visible element with "audioNumber" id! Put a DIV with that id and it will work.

Comment: This JSFiddle with spelling correction might explain the down vote!

https://jsfiddle.net/SKJoy2001/0j4wyhLs/3/

Answer (score 0):

You just not only have to use `textContent` but also have to use correct `id` in `document.getElementById` in `play()` function

Please check the below snippet, it is working and showing the index of the song from the array in button.

```js
var audio = new Audio();
var audiolist = new Array('https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504645/BatShevaAudio/chiaki_tpast4.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504643/BatShevaAudio/sean_mzegyf.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504636/BatShevaAudio/yoni_z4suqd.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504636/BatShevaAudio/Billy_x8srx0.mp3',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvugxz59z/video/upload/v1621504627/BatShevaAudio/Matan_sj77wi.mp3');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

function play() {
  if (audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
  }
  let rndnumber = getRandomInt(0, 4);

  audio.src = audiolist[rndnumber];
  audio.play();
  document.getElementById("rndnumber").textContent = rndnumber;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play()" id="rndnumber"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Im really not sure why but this didn't work for me, maybe it has something to do with the fact that i'm working in Webflow which is super uncomfortable for writing code or some other weird reason...